# Control email sent on behalf of different address with Outlook Rules

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, spam-prevention

I frequently filter spam by domain from companies that do not respect "unsubscribe".  In Outlook, I use the rules wizard to set a rule where specific words ("@rudecompany.com") appear in the sender's address.

Recently, I've been getting spam "from noreply@salesforce.com sent on behalf of person@rudecompany.com".  The sender's address is noreply@salesforce.com so my rule does not apply.

Using Outlook Rules, how can I target all noreply@salesforce.com email sent on behalf of anybody @rudecompany.com without blocking all @salesforce.com email?

Comment: Look at the actual raw body of the email and target something in there.

Comment: How is your issue going? Any updates?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depending on how the header is written, you usually can recognize one of the following “Sent on behalf of” methods so you can get quite specific when setting up your rule. Step by step guidance refer to: [Rule to sort out “on behalf of” messages](https://www.msoutlook.info/question/709)

And here's a similar thread you could refer to as well: [Rule for reception of "on behalf of"](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook_com/forum/all/rule-for-reception-of-on-behalf-of/07eb6504-7661-45dc-ace2-28ed7cc0e7f8)

Comment: This solves my issue; I am using with specific words in the message header.

Answer (score 0):

Steps for OWA:

1. View the message header by clicking the menu/more options/three dots button in an email. Go down to View and then Message Details.
2. Look for a line within the Message details that has the email of the primary sender. In your case you're looking for "person@rudecompany.com". I typically find a line that says *(envelope from person@rudecompany.com)*.
3. Copy *(envelope from person@rudecompany.com)* to your clipboard.
4. Close the message details and create a new rule (Create rule > More options)
5. I name mine something like "Autoarchive all mass messages from person@rudecompany.com".
6. **Add a condition:** "Message header includes" from the drop down and then put (envelope from person@rudecompany.com) in the empty field.
7. Set your action as you wish (archive or delete)
8. Add an exception if you want to catch emails that were direct to you from that email. This is useful if you do still interact with person@rudecompany.com on a one-to-one basis. The exception is "I'm on the To or CC line".

YMMV - only do this is you're sure you won't miss anything critical from that sender.